# Является ли ошибкой словосочетание "цель выполнена"?

Tags: лексика

Добрый день. Знаю, что правильно использовать "цель достигнута", но в тираж уже ушел вариант "цель выполнена". Является ли это словосочетание грубой ошибкой, или можно это пережить?

Comment: Правильное употребление вы указали верно - "цель достигнута", в силовых структурах нередко используется эвфемизм "цель отработана".

Можно ли пережить? Ну, это вопрос уже не относящийся к тематике русского языка. Кто-то из-за пропущенной запятой со стыда сгорит, кто-то вордом проверяет орфографию и ему хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что ошибка в сочетаемости слов серьёзная, хотя у менеджеров в текстах такое и попадается. "Цель" даже в самых абстрактных выражениях сохраняет "геометрический" смысл, ассоциируясь с направлением движения, с приближением или удалением при движении в этом направлении, с отклонением от цели и пр. Можно говорить лишь о "выполнении" задач, связанных с *достижением цели* или с приближением к ней.